# Error: invalid address (argument="address", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.1.0)

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm Getting this error when trying to deploy a smart contract with a function:

> Error: invalid address (argument="address", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.1.0) (argument="tokenAddress", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)

Here is my code:

```
 const handlePresale = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const web3 = await getWeb3();
    const abiData = SafeHubPresaleAbi;
    const contractAddress = "0x4498F943E0a13D70B28e7565CF4E33bF443e6Bf9";

    const duration = {
      seconds: function (val) {
        return val;
      },
      minutes: function (val) {
        return val * this.seconds(60);
      },
      hours: function (val) {
        return val * this.minutes(60);
      },
      days: function (val) {
        return val * this.hours(24);
      },
      weeks: function (val) {
        return val * this.days(7);
      },
      years: function (val) {
        return val * this.days(365);
      },
    };

    const latestTime = new Date().getTime();
    const openingTime = latestTime + duration.minutes(1);
    const closingTime = openingTime + duration.minutes(10);
    const liqAddingTime = closingTime + duration.minutes(5);

    let _info = {
      address : "0x4498F943E0a13D70B28e7565CF4E33bF443e6Bf9",
      tokenPrice : web3.utils.toWei("10", "ether"),
      hardCap: web3.utils.toWei("100", "ether"),
      softCap: web3.utils.toWei("30", "ether"),
      minInv: web3.utils.toWei("0.1", "ether"),
      maxInv: web3.utils.toWei("5", "ether"),
      openingTime: openingTime,
      closingTime: closingTime,
  };

    let _uniInfo = {
      listingPrice: web3.utils.toWei("20", "ether"),
      liqTime: liqAddingTime,
      lockTime: 365,
      precentLock: 25,
    };

    let _stringInfo = {
      listingName: "WER sale",
    };

    const preslaeContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(
      abiData,
      contractAddress
    );
    // console.log(preslaeContract.methods)

    preslaeContract.methods
    .createPresale(_info,_uniInfo,_stringInfo)
    .call((err, result) => {
      console.log(result), console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Solidity constructor:

```
constructor(address _safuFactoryAddress, address _safuDevAddress) public {
    require(_safuFactoryAddress != address(0));
    require(_safuDevAddress != address(0));

    safuFactoryAddress = payable(_safuFactoryAddress);
    safuDevAddress = payable(_safuDevAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

since there are still no answers yet, but over 1k views though, I'll leave here a solution if anyone else is facing the same error.

The solidity constructor in your example expects 2 arguments of type address. This means if you deploy your contract you also need to provide those 2.

**As for the deployment:**
No matter how you deploy your contract, providing all constructor arguments should solve your problem and your contract should be able to get deployed now.

If you work with truffle, you need to adjust your [deployer](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations.html#deployer) ...`/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js` and pass 2 addresses to satisfy the constructor parameters.

```
var SafeHubPresale = artifacts.require("./SafeHubPresale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SafeHubPresale, [address1], [address2]);
};
```

**The same applies for test:**
let's say:

```
var myContract = await SafeHubPresale.new(accounts[1], accounts[2], {from: accounts[0], gas: 0});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those in Remix, select the drop down next to "deploy" and you will need to provide a "to" & "from" address for this to work

[image: Remix Drop Down Option]

Answer (score 0):

In your smart contract, more than one argument may present and cannot fulfill its value when you deploy. When you deploy you take these values and call `deploy()` it's working correctly.

In your constructor

```
constructor(address _safuFactoryAddress, address _safuDevAddress)
```

more than one address value present there you may not provide this value when you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to test out [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/vrf).

I had 2 problems:

#### 1. I was deploying the wrong contract

In the Remix sidebar, I needed to switch the contract to `VRFD20.sol`:

[image]

#### 2. I was using a Remix VM

The Chainlink VRF service only works on real networks (like mainnet or sepolia). Changing the Remix Environment to "Injected Provider - MetaMask" fixed the error.